# Creating downloadable information dynamically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How to create downloadable information(small,medium,large) dynamically(at time of uploding image and save it.),before saving product,using images details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento API to create downloadable product information dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = Mage::getModel('cart/mycart')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId()); foreach($items as $item) : $incrementId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($item->getOrderId())->getIncrementId();//->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$item->getItemId());

$linkPurchased = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($incrementId, 'order_increment_id'); $downloadableItems = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item_collection') ->addFieldToFilter('purchased_id', $linkPurchased->getPurchasedId()); //->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $item->getItemId()); $links = array(); foreach ($downloadableItems as $li): $links[] = Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', array('id' => $li->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true)); endforeach; foreach($links as $link): ?> " target="_blank">
```